# C# Regex for at least one letter and at least one number

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm attempting to check verify that the password had at least one letter and number.

The following doesn't seem to work.

Password could be  "tester1"  or "11111111t" etc.

Can not be all letters or all digits.

Any ideas?

```
const string pattern = @"/[a-z].*\d|\d.*[a-z]/";
var match = Regex.Match(password, pattern);
```

Solved:

```
var rule1 = password.Any(char.IsLetter);
var rule2 = password.Any(char.IsNumber);
```

This worked as well:

```
const string pattern = @"[a-z].*\d|\d.*[a-z]";
```

Comment: If it is not *must* don't use regex. This way would be easier to maintain, easier to add new rules. For ex, See the first answer and think you want to add new conditions to passwords.

Comment: I'd personally check 2 regex, one for letters and 1 for numbers.  it's more simple that way

Comment: @SamIam No need for regex to do what you say.

Comment: Guffa said it already, but the leading and trailing slashes shouldn't be there when working with C#.  That's one of your problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using regex, I would use simple rules which would easier to maintain. For example:

```
var rule1 = str.All(char.IsLetter);
var rule2 = str.All(char.IsNumber);
```

And you can enrich your rules by `char.IsLower`, `char.IsUpper` etc.

Comment: `str.Any()`, no? (Though I'm sympathetic to the non-regex approach!)

Comment: @dlev if rule1 or rule2 is true then don't accept it as passwd.

Comment: @I4V That negated approach won't work. Take the empty string, or a string that only contains characters that are neither letters nor numbers. Those certainly contain "at least one letter and at least one number", but both of your rules evaluate to false.

Comment: Sure, but `Any()` will inspect fewer characters in the vast majority of cases (since most users will have some letters but possibly forget to omit numbers.) Either way, code that demonstrates the usage would ease the confusion, I think.

Comment: @I4V - It'd be better to use `Any()` and check that both rule1 and rule2 are satisfied.  It's more efficient that way, as the algorithm will terminate sooner.

Comment: @CodesInChaos:  If the _only_ rules are "Can not be all letters or all digits", then the empty string is valid.  `rule3` could be `str.Length > 7`.

Comment: OK guys you got the idea. I think we all know how to write it when it comes to a real code

Comment: @AustinSalonen has two different rules in his question. The topic says "Regex for atleast one letter and atleast one number" and the body says "Can not be all letters or all digits." I assume the rule in the topic is the one that they actually want, since it makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

This will do it...

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).+$
```

I'm using [positive lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=)` to accomplish this, and then allowing any character `.` one or more times.  This way the user is allowed to enter special characters, punctuation and such.

Comment: I'd probably make those `.*`'s non-greedy. Why check the whole string if you can know something near the beginning isn't a letter (or subsequently a digit)?

Comment: @Kenneth - So what would you change it to?

Comment: Just make it non-greedy:  `.*?`. It's not that big of a deal, though.

Comment: @KennethK. - That's what I thought you meant.  I tried it that way too and there was no performance difference (using the benchmark feature at http://regexhero.net/tester/ ).

Comment: Agreed. Chalk my comment up to a micro-optimization. I don't suspect it would make a difference until the strings were very long. I've just gotten myself in the habit of specifying my patterns very specifically. Sometimes, though, it just doesn't matter which way you do it! Cheers =)

Answer (score 2):

here's one

```
((.*\d.*[a-zA-Z].*)|(.*[a-zA-Z].*\d.*))
```

Answer (score 2):

Slashes around the pattern is used in languages that has regular expression literals. C# doesn't have that.

Remove the slashes from the pattern:

```
const string pattern = @"[a-z].*\d|\d.*[a-z]";
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex for at least one uppercase, one lower case, one number, one special character and at least 8 chars long:

`^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9 :])(?=.{8,})`

Comment: Isn't * for any number of character including zero? Should + be used for at least one character?